# How do I stop jQuery hover flood?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my `"menu"` items that have an image, and by hovering them, jQuery brings out a text and a description for that image. However, I could not find any way to block or stop this effect from flooding.

[See the example](http://ws4.opiferum.net/~opiportal/sites/60/etusivu), from this try moving your cursor around the four boxes, fast, you will see that they kind of queue, and I don't really want that to happen.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();    
    if($("#editor").val()!="1")
    {
        $('.thumbnail').hover(
            function(){
              $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(450)
         },
         function(){
               $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(800)
         }
     }); 
});
```

Ways to stop this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `.stop()` ([jQuery API reference](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)) to your selector. It will cancel an ongoing animation

```
$(this).find('.caption').stop().fadeIn(450)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly fine after adding it on both of the fades!